# File Constructors Explanation

Tags: java, file

I was unable to understand the following file constructors.

```
public File(String parent, String child) and 
public File(File parent, String child)
```

What do the parameters `parent` and `child` mean for the file? When can I use these? I have done few programs related to file but I have never used these. I usually use

```
public File(String pathname)
```

I have read [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) but I could not figure out when and how to use these constructors. Could someone please explain and give examples.

Comment: See. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Just to add one to the answers already given, I have most used them in situations where I have, for example, a File object pointing to a directory, and I need to create one or more files within that directory. Rather than concatenating a string or make a new File pointer every time, I would simply maintain that one constant File directory pointer (the parent), and pass in the name of the file (the child) to the second constructor you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Explanation

The `parent` parameter is the parent directory of the `child` file name or relative file path.

Where `parent` is a File instance, it is a directory file.  Where `parent` is a String, it's simply that directory in `pathname` terms.

---

### Examples

Consider the following partial file system:

```
Documents
    Homework
    Classwork
    Tests
```

Rather than declaring each new file with "Documents\Subdir", you can declare the Documents directory as a file, and use it as the `parent` File of the other File instances, like so:

```
File documents = new File("Documents");
File tests = new File("Documents/Tests"); // new File(String);

File homework = new File(documents, "Homework"); // new File(File, String)

File classwork = new File("Documents", "Classwork"); // new File(String, String)
```

---

### Real-world application

In my experience, I've used applications that provide an API containing a method that returns the directory file in which third-party "plugins" are allowed to save/read files.  Without the `File(File, String)` constructor, I would need to convert the directory file into an absolute path and append my target file to it.

In the following example, `Environment.getProgramDirectory()` returns the directory file in which permissions are granted.

```
File settingsFile = new File(Environment.getProgramDirectory(), "settings.txt");
```

Comment: child parameter does not have to be a file name. It can be a folder name or a relative path.

Comment: A folder is a file by definition, but I added that clarification anyway.

Comment: I think the OP says that she has already read that much in the docs, and is looking for explanation to when/why part.

Comment: @BheshGurung Thanks for pointing that out; I've added an example and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain with some examples:

Assuming that you have the following structure:

```
/dir1
  dir11
```

The constructor that you usually use `new File("/dir1/dir11")` is equivalent to

`new File("/dir1", "dir11")` (constructor taking 2 `String` as arguments)

and also equivalent to

`new File(new File("/dir1"), "dir11")` (constructor using a `File` as first argument).

Answer (score 1):

"The parent abstract pathname is taken to denote a directory, and the child pathname string is taken to denote either a directory or a file. "  As specified on the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

`Parent` will point to the `Directory`

`Child` will be its `Contents`..