# Cannot create file with Java using the Parent and Child parameters of the new File constructor

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a file using Java. I want to create this file in a sub-folder of my "Documents" directory. I want this sub-folder to be based today's date.

I **thought** I new how to use the `File` class and `file.mkdirs()` method properly, but I guess I don't.

Here is what I have:

```
public class FileTest {
    private static final String sdfTimestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
    private static final SimpleDateFormat timestampSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(sdfTimestampFormat);

    private static final String sdfDirFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dirSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(sdfDirFormat);

    public static void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Date rightNow = new Date();
        String data = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String filename = "file.txt";

        String directory_name = path + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Documents" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + dirSDF.format(rightNow);

        File file = new File(directory_name, filename);

        if(file.mkdirs()){
              String outstring = timestampSDF.format(rightNow) + " | " + data + System.getProperty("line.separator");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
              fos.write(outstring.getBytes());
              fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening is that the following ***directory*** is created:

```
 C:\Users\<username>\Documents\2018-08-03\file.txt\
```

I was under the impression that the `Parent` parameter of the new `File` constructor was the base directory, and the `Child` paramater of the new `File` constructor was the file itself.

Is this not the case? Do I need two `File` objects, one for the base directory and another for the file?

What I want is this:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\2018-08-03\file.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: just a hint: `File`, despite its name, is just a path - can be kind of confusing.... that is, `mkdirs` is used to create the directory with the represented path

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger What is confusing is why there is a `Parent` and `Child` parameter, when all you really need is the `Child`. It doesn't really make any sense. You would figure the `Parent` would be the base directory and the `Child` would be the end file itself.

Comment: well, for me it always did make sense, at least after the initial idea that `File` is a file vanished. It is kind of just a help for the programmer, obviously you can do the resolution/concatenation yourself and use the single parameter constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdirs()` will do directories (if they don't exist) for each element in your path.

So you can use `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` to not make a directory for your `file.txt`

**Edit:  Something to consider**

`mkdirs()` only returns true if it actually created directories. If they already existed or there was a problem creating them it will return `false`

Since you are trying to run this multiple times to append to your text your logic will not run inside your `if-statement`

I would change it to:

```
boolean created = true;
if(!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
    created = file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
if (created) {
    String outstring = timestampSDF.format(rightNow) + " | " + data + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    fos.write(outstring.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: @Brian - Javadoc: "Creates a new File instance from a parent pathname string and a child pathname string. ...  each pathname string is converted into an abstract pathname and the child abstract pathname is resolved against the parent." (so you don't have to do it)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Sounds superfluous to me, an extra layer of useless redundancy.

Comment: @Brian perhaps this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165381/file-constructors-explanation) enlightens why the use of `File()` constuctor with a parent parameter

Comment: @Brian java.io.File is a very very old class (it’s been around since Java 1.0!).  It has some issues, which is why it has been replaced with the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class.  Using Path, you would do something like `Path directory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents", dirSDF.format(rightNow)); Path file = directory.resolve(filename);`.  Does that address the redunancy you speak of?

Comment: @Brian useless? if you want to resolve the child path by hand, do it. And by that logic somehow the whole compiler is superfluous, we could just program in byte code, or even in assembler.